# What is format of Natural Earth SQLite database GEOMETRY column?

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, natural-earth

I need to extract coordinates of polygon boundary points in order to draw a map in my application. Does anyone know what is format of "GEOMETRY" column in this database? It doesn't look like .SHP format, rather something else.

I'm looking for a documentation or explaination the binary data, so I can use it.

This is sqlite example: https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/blob/master/packages/natural_earth_vector.sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I think I found it by myself. It's "Well-known binary format". What an irony.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary

I successfully used http://geophp.net/ programming library to operate on those geometry data.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Spatialite uses a special format for the Geometry databse "blob". Not exactly WKB. See  [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/wkt-wkb.html). If you need a standards compliant WKT or WKB representation, then you should use ST_AsText() or ST_AsBinary() .

Comment: I successfully used WKB programming library to decode this column, so I assume it's actually WKB. "Blob" is just container for any binary data (images, audio, whatever).